# Docker Engine not seeing installed Nvidia runtime

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 22.04, I installed docker and docker desktop.

After installing the Nvidia docker runtime via the Nvidia docker toolkit, Nvidia runtime is not visible after system restart. I updated the Docker Json file to add the run time and it still did not work.

Nvidia runtime was visible after installation but prior to system restart but now it is not seeable under docker info and containers which use it fail to run as it's an unknown runtime.

I tried reinstalling the Nvidia runtime but it won't come up still.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to enable Docker to start after system restart using,

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```